# Is it possible sharing computing resource between two windows PC in LAN? Open for more specific description

Tags: cloud, rpc, share, lan

Here is the plan.

I have a ASUS netbook running ATOM cpu, it's weak in processing big program.
But, i have a normal laptop running core i5 CPU, It's strong.
I like using remote desktop connecting provided by Win7 between two PC. It makes me easy to see what happened on my laptop through the screen of my netbook.
Now, i want to have the laptop help the netbook do some computing job.

You know what i mean?
For example, if i want to run VS2010 on my netbook, it performance weak on the netbook.
We know there are lots of jobs behind opening a VS2010. So , i want the LAPTOP do this for netbook, then return the necessity data to the netbook.After that, the netbook will render the window on the netbook. But, actually,the computing jobs were finished by the netbook.
By the way, the netbook and laptop are in the same 802.11n WLAN.

Is there gruf can do me some favour???I don't know how to do that, or what technology can help me.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial addition to Windows called incredibuild that is able to do load balancing over a network. See: http://www.xoreax.com/ . I'm frequently using it at work to compile our large source tree from a virtual windows box by using the CPU-resources of my coworkers (real) windows boxes.

Answer (score 0):

No, standard editions of Windows do not support this type of clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a little bit broad to be accomplished by a single solution. As you know, making things distributed is not easy, as a result, each computing problem may have its own method for being distributed.

As Dov has pointed rightly in one of the answers of your question, you may use incredibuild to make your build problem distributed. But this just gets your sources built. If you have any other compute-intensive problems (e.g. rendering a movie, text extraction from an image, zipping a large file, etc) you should find specific solutions to them.

This is actually because Windows (as same as Linux and Mac) is a network operating system (NOS), not a distributed operating system (DOS). There are a set of scientific distributed operating systems (such as [Amoeba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_distributed_operating_system)) that can share the physical resources for you in a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, did you see Inferno Operation System guys? This gonna be awesome.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_%28operating_system%29